# How to solve angular PathLocationStrategy(html5 route) refresh 404 without reidirect all resources to home page

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, angular-ui-router

I use Angular7 and Node 8.11.4 as web application, now i need to remove "#" from the url, so i change locationStrategy form `HashLocationStrategy` to `PathLocationStrategy` and add `<base href="/">` in index.html.

It works but you know after that it will get 404 error after refresh page, i know how to redirect all resources to home page, but my purpose is to redirect some resources to specfic component or page, because i need to visit these pages directly not from home page, this is my question, i searched on google and found most of the rolution is to redirect to home page but not the specific page, i know Angular vue react all use front end router, but i still want to know if it's possible to visit specific page directly.

Such as: visit `http://localhost:4200/aaa`, then without redirect to home page localhost:4200, it can show page aaa directly. **/aaa** is a path that route to a Angular component.

Please post your answer if you have any solution or have the same question on `PathLocationStrategy` `html5 router`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue has been fixed, seems many people have the same issue, so post my solution here.

For Node server:

In the bottom of your `server.js`, add below method:

```
const fs = require("fs");
app.use((req, res)=>{
  let rs = fs.createReadStream(`${__dirname}/dist/{your project name}/index.html`);
  res.writeHead(200, {"Content-type": "text/html"});
  rs.pipe(res);
})
```

`__filename`: this is Node variable, it means the file name of the current module.

`fs`: The `fs` module provides an API for interacting with the file system

This is a route for that couldn't find resource in your server, such as `/aaa`, when you
  try to refresh page /aaa after change to PathLocationStrategy, you will get 404 error, 
  after you add this route, all non-found resource will goto this route, then 
 `fs.createReadStream(${__dirname}/dist/{your project name}/index.html)` will redirect your resource to index.html, after that Angular index.html will handle your route and redirect to the correct page.